# Kafka producer changing the number of partition and consumer keep going down

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer, broker, producer

I have been working on my Kafka project for a while and I have run into some issues that go beyond my understanding.

so the problem is that I have created a topic with 6 partition in kafdrop and then when I ran my producer code, the existing topic that I created in kafdrop changed to 10 partitions. however, 4 newly added partitions had no record in them.

and while running the server, i have matched 24 partition for 24 consumers however one of the consumer seemed to be failing and in order to test this situation i changed the partition to 23 and now 2 of my consumer went out of action.

I'm having a really hard time trying to solve or understand the logic behind this problem

thank you beforehand

Comment: Please add code samples for your producer/consumer as well as error logs.

Comment: i cant show you the codes im sorry but would there be any kind of logic that makes that happen?